# 'I would be so grateful if...' rude?

Tags: offensive-language, politeness, email

I am a high school student and I often use 'I would be so grateful if you could take a moment to...' or 'I would be so grateful if you could help me.' or something like that when I am writing  an email to teachers.

My QUESTION IS..
IS IT RUDE? I really don't want to be rude and I have been always trying to be nice and be polite to my teachers. But I don't know if my 'I would be so grateful if you could..' emails are rude/un polite. Could you guys help me? Thanks .

Comment: Sometimes being over-solicitous can be interpreted as sarcasm. If you dial the gushiness down a couple of clicks to where it would look like normal politeness, then you'll probably be well enough received.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  I would be so grateful if you would take a moment to tour the site and read the FAQ.  It is hard to interpret tone in texts.

Comment: I can't interpret it as anything but polite—and polite in a formal way.

Comment: You could toe it down a bit by using "'I would be grateful" at the end, and without *SO* in it.  If you could do such and such *'I would be grateful*. Just asking and using Thank You at the end is often enough.

Comment: Reminds me of Churchill’s “pray”.